# iMac screen freezes (audio/mic/etc still function but video freezes)

Tags: catalina, imac, performance

I've been having a few odd issues with a new iMac. Screen will freeze occasionally (as will my camera if I'm on a video call) but my microphone, audio, and mouse will still move. If it happens on a video/audio call - others can still hear me and I can still hear them.

I've looked through the logs to the best of my ability but cannot see anything that's going wrong (albeit there's a lot of logs to dig through). I've followed all the normal standard troubleshooting steps but to no avail. There's no rhyme nor reason/regularity to the freezes either (I've ran the system with only a video calling app open and everything else killed and yet it still happens).

I'm at a loss, as is Apple Support, as to what's causing this or how to even diagnose it as it doesn't seem to register anywhere.

**Specs:**

```
OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H524)
iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2020)
Processor: 3.8 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i7
Memory: 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500 XT 8 GB
```

Additional information: I have 2x Lenovo 27" screens connected to this iMac

Comment: Is this happening with the whole system (within the operating system)? It sounds more like a hiccup within the video conferencing transmission itself. Please [edit] into your question the application that you are using and more details about what is happening when you experience this behavior.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the video conferencing app - it happens no matter what video conferencing app is being used and sometimes happens without using any app (although it's rarer) - hence the "**if** I'm still on video call"

Comment: If "it happens no matter what video conferencing app is being used" then the problem is with the network or ISP. Please explain how it "sometimes happens without using any app". What indications are you seeing (or not seeing) that your screen freezes?

Comment: How on earth is a screen freeze (where video content or moving items on the page freeze) anything to do with my ISP or network? That's not how it works.

Comment: There are some problems that are posted on here that are difficult to diagnose without specific information. We are not in front of your computer and therefore rely on you to supply these details. It will be very difficult to offer a solution without additional information.

Comment: Appreciate that, but it's pretty obvious it's not the video calling apps or the network (how on earth ISP/network issues would cause a screen to freeze, but the cursor not, is beyond me). All I'm looking for is a nudge in the right direction as to start troubleshooting this issue